# pandas dataframe adding new columns based on labels

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
name   gender
John    1
Alice   0
Michael 1
```

I have another data point called Port which indicated where these people embarked. Port has different values (say, 1,2 3). Suppose John embarked on port 1, Alice on 2, and Michael on 3.

How can I get the following table using pandas:

```
name  gender  port1   port2   port3
John    1       1       0       0
Alice   0       0       1       0
Michael 1       0       0       1
```

**EDIT**
The way I am doing it now is semi-manually for each label.

```
port_dict = {'port1': 0, 'port2': 1, 'port3': 2}
for port, num in port_dict.items():    
    train_df[port] = train_df.Embarked[train_df.Embarked==num]
    train_df[port].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

But this gives me all 0s in port{1,2,3} columns.

**EDIT2**
Actually, the above solution works. But is there a better way?

Comment: What is your approach, where is your code and which part were you stuck ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where the `Embarked` attribute on your `train_df` is coming from.
This is the way I'd approach the problem, don't know if it could be described as a better way.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John', 'Alice', 'Michael'], 
              'gender': [1, 0, 1], 'port_num': [1, 2, 3] })

for i in set(df.port_num.values):    
    df['port{0}'.format(i)] = (df.port_num == i).astype(int)
```

This obviously won't work with ports named more meaningfully than `port1`, you'd either need the `port_num` column to be the port name string or to build the dictionary as in your **EDIT**.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following set of functions:

```
def discrim(row, catField, cat, srcField):
    if srcField in row:
        if row[catField]==cat:
            return row[srcField]
        else:
            pass
    else:
        if row[catField]==cat:
            return srcField
    return 0

def CatToAtt(data, source, catField):
    clist = list(data[catField].unique())
    for a in clist:
        data['_att_' + str(a)] = data.apply(lambda x: discrim(x,catField, a, source), axis=1)
    return clist

def getAtts(data):
    alist = []
    for a in data.columns:
        if "_att_" in a:
            alist.append ( a)
    return alist
```

Use CatToAtt to convert a field containing categorised data into a group of fields that contain a binary {1,0} identifying whether the row is of a particular category type. It's useful for preparing data for random-forests, or other statistic/machine learning processes.

For example, say I've got a field called "Port" that contains a value from ["London", "Southampton", "Cherbourg", "Queenstown"] in a dataframe called titanic. I could run the following:

```
CatToAtt(titanic, 1, "Port")
```

And this will add the following columns to the titanic dataframe

```
["_att_London", "_att_Southampton", "_att_Cherbourg", "_att_Queenstown"]
```

Each populated with a 1 if there's a match with the "Port" column and the appropriate category value, and a 0 if it's not.

If later, you want to quickly get a list of all the columns created in this way, just call getAtts to return a list (It assumes nobody is going to use the "*att*" naming convention used here - reasonably safe, but editable in case you come across some exceptions)

An alternative you might try could be:

```
def CatToAttAlternative(data, source, catField):
    clist = list(data[catField].unique())
    for a in clist:
        data[str(catField) + str(a)] = data.apply(lambda x: discrim(x, catField, a, source), axis=1)
    return clist
```

Which effectively does the same thing, just with a naming convention that uses the source-column-name as a prefix instead of "*att*" which if applied to your example should return results that more closely match your example (i.e. one of {Port1, Port2, Port3} etc)

Hope that helps, let me know if I can explain it any further.